# View my questions with unaccepted answers

Tags: support, accepted-answer, accept-rate

There is this new acceptance rate feature that appears beneath my signature card when I ask a question.

How do I display all my questions with unaccepted answers? How can I easily see the list of questions that have not been checked as accepted?

Comment: +1 - Not a bad idea to have this feature of sorting the questions based on accepted answers.

Comment: Related: [Sort questions in user propfile by unaccepted or date accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60557/sort-questions-in-user-profile-by-unaccepted-or-date-accepted), possibly a duplicate.

Comment: Actually, the proper duplicate would probably be [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers).

Comment: Thanks guys - what do I need to do to have this merged with the duplicate?

Comment: @Neil, you can always flag for a moderator to have a look, and explain that you want a merge; I've just done that for you for this question.

Comment: Acceptance rate is no longer displayed anywhere.

Comment: To search across ***all*** Stack Exchange sites, see: '**[How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119575/351462)**'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use this as a search:

```
user:me hasaccepted:0
```

Comment: Why isn't there a simple way to do this in the user interfae?

Comment: Is there a way to do this across all SE sites?

Comment: @void.pointer To search ***all*** SE sites, see '**[How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119575/351462)**'

Answer (score 13):

Use the [less-crappy search](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/):

> https://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3A2561+hasaccepted%3A0

Answer (score 10):

I think you can do this using the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

`user:me hasaccepted:0 closed:0`

in the search box in the top right

Answer (score 1):

In your profile questions with accepted answers show differently than answers without; just like on the question browsing pages of SO. On SO and meta the number of answers has a background of green, on SU I believe it is blue and on SF red.