# A filter within my profile to show questions with no accepted answer

Tags: feature-request

Please can we get a filter or additional tab within the profile screen to show questions I have asked with no accepted answer.

Perhaps render the acceptance %age as a link to said questions.

In this way we could quickly see the sorts of questions that someone has been unable to accept answers to.

Comment: I believe this is not a dup... the previous was asking how to... this is suggesting a feature to improve the current system.

Comment: Indeed, whilst the referenced question is useful, it does not fulfil the requested feature as this suggestion is about enhancing the user interface.

Comment: Reopened ... Thanks for the extra consideration guys.

Comment: Good idea! It'll be a gentle reminder that answerers like to have their response accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start:

[**View My Questions With Unaccepted Answers**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)

Comment: thanks very much. that is very useful and will certainly do for the moment. I suspect however, that this is something that I will forget and have to keep revisiting this question in order to remind myself of. I would be nice to have this as a built in tab in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to encourage user's to be active and to accept answers to their questions, I believe this would be a useful feature to help encouraging that.