# I'd like to be able to see all of my unanswered questions in my questions profile

Tags: feature-request, questions, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort questions in user profile by “Unaccepted” or “Date accepted”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60557/sort-questions-in-user-profile-by-unaccepted-or-date-accepted)

I'd like to be able to sort the questions in my profile by whether or not I have a chosen an answer. This helps keep acceptance ratios high.

This is different from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/unanswered-question-sort-order-on-profile-pages) because that question wants to see questions with zero answers. I want to see questions that have answer where I didn't select the proper answer.

Before my feature request:

[image: before]

After my feature request:

[image: after]

Comment: It's different from that question, but not so much [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60557/sort-questions-in-user-profile-by-unaccepted-or-date-accepted). Also related: [ein](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers), [zwei](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/a-filter-within-my-profile-to-show-questions-with-no-accepted-answer), [drei](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68241/how-to-list-all-of-my-questions-that-i-havent-select-the-best-answers)...

Comment: another [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69304/what-about-add-a-unanswered-questions-tab-to-the-user-page)

Comment: You are both correct. Voted to close. I did not see those in my previous searches.

Comment: @Grace Note: eins!

Comment: @Lady I suppose you missed the time I misspelled fünf, too.

Comment: @Grace: Where have you misspelled fünf? I will beat the grace out of your note!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for: `user:me hasaccepted:0`