# How do I find all of my questions without an accepted answer?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View My questions with Unaccepted Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)

I wish to go over the questions I have asked in the past, to see if there is an answer I should accept.  Therefore how do I find all my questions without an accepted answer that the system things should have an accepted answer?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search feature can do this for you:

```
user:me hasaccepted:0
```