# Is it possible to find most commonly used username in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, statistics

Finally, I have decided to delete my account. But as someone said my questions will still be there, but with a greyed out name.

I am thinking of changing my profile name to something which is most widely used so that it becomes difficult track my questions.

Something like SAM perhaps. Is there any query which I can execute to get that?

EDIT: someone told me that my last username stays there, so you mean it will always be "Please delete me" as per the FAQ?

Comment: Are you ashamed of your questions?

Comment: I will feel ashamed if my company mate reads that , i told in some posts how company people are idiots. so definitely i do'nt want to take risk. i need their reference as well so . .

Comment: Why not edit out the discrimination? Slander doesn't really belong, anyway...

Comment: Well the whole discussion is here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/how-do-i-find-all-of-my-questions-without-an-accepted-answer

Comment: That's a pretty short discussion, with nothing untoward looking.

Comment: That doesn't look like the right question to me.

Comment: @Mr.Disapp well perhaps only the wearer knows where the shoe pinches

Comment: You can opt to put "please delete me" in the About Me section of your profile, not necessarily your username. That lets you retain a generic username.

Comment: Old data always exists.  Even if you change your username to something generic, every question is linked to the UserID, not just the name.  It would be trivial to go to your user page and look at all your questions.  Even if you delete your old account, someone with an old data dump file can find your username, and the whole history of everything you did.

Comment: I think you've gotten yourself trapped in a paradox. Even if you delete or obfuscate your "undesirable" content, these meta-discussions **about** the undesirable content still remain and could be found. This means you have to open some meta-meta-discussions about how to delete the meta-discussions so that they don't lead back to the original content you are trying to hide. And then you need meta-meta-meta-discussions to... etc., etc. It's like you're leaving a trail of poisonous breadcrumbs; a trail that disappears when eaten by forest animals, but reappears in the form of animal carcasses.

Comment: @Kibbee well for that user has to download more than 3gb of dump , then sort the data , then find my questions , even if i have to do that , i will give it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/98114/most-used-display-names

John, Mike, Chris, Alex, David … pick one :)

Comment: ha ha i love john

Comment: I'm surprised balpha's not on the list.

Comment: Anonymous is also pretty decent, at 367. Even though it only has 40, I'd go with Gabe personally.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed that you became "John" and your account is deleted now.

Comment: ALL DONE BUDDY , thanks guys for all ur help .

Answer (score 0):

Just use `anon` or `Anonymous`. However, you won't be able to change @replies!

Comment: I can't do much bout that. someone told me that my last username stays there , so u mean it will always be "Please delete me" as per FAQ