# Feature request: Ability to see questions I have not accepted an answer for

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View My questions with Unaccepted Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)

I'd like to do the right thing and accept answers on questions where appropriate, but the current view for paging through my questions makes this a little awkward, and I was wondering if there could be more options for sorting and filtering the list of questions I've asked on the user page so I can review those for which I've not accepted an answer (and improve my question in order to get an answer worth accepting if necessary).

Many thanks in advance.