# Clicking on my percentage of answers accepted could take me to the list of my questions without accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

I've noticed that in those places that show my percentage of accepted answers that it is not clickable.

Previously I had found it tricky to get to my list of questions without accepted answers.

Since most fields are clickable I think it would be a fitting feature to link a user's accept-rate to this list.

Comment: where do u find that accepted answers?

Comment: @Damodar: I can't remember! I know it's around because I've used it to go over my old questions and accept more answers. Implementing this feature would certainly make it easier to find.

Comment: @Damodar: See Lance's answer below. You need to find out your user number then do an advanced search: `user:###### hasaccepted:0` where ###### is your user number.

Comment: Using `user:me` will also work, for your own list.

Comment: @Damodar: There was a question about it actually: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would probably be an easy thing to link the rate to the advanced search:

```
user:###### hasaccepted:0 answers:1
```

for any particular user.

Comment: In the context of the question, I'd throw in `answers:1` as well.