# View my answers to questions with no accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer, search

Somewhat related to [View my questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16869), but from the other end.

Can we have a filter option for our answers (that we have posted to another user's questions) to only show our answers to questions which do not have an accepted answer? This way, it would be easier for us to go back to unresolved questions to improve our answers. Currently we can only see which of our answers were or were not accepted, but there is nothing to indicate whether another answer has been accepted on that same question without actually going to the question.

Comment: +1, you've given me an idea, sort by votes and go to the last page and start improving there...

Comment: Hmm... Your motivation sounds good, but my first thought upon reading this was, "great, a tool for folks to harass askers to accept answers."

Answer (score 11):

They could solve this by modifying `hasaccepted:0` to key off the question that an answer was posted to, instead of the post.  Right now it will always return nothing if used with other filters that only give answers, like `user:me is:answer hasaccepted:0`.

Comment: Is isanswer actually a filter? It doesn't work for me and isn't listed on the search page.

Comment: +50 (bounty) for what seems (to me) to be a very viable solution.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to what was suggested by Lance Roberts, as "hasaccepted" is used to filter out questions, and "isanswer:1" shows the list of the answers, there could be an "ianswered:1" that would filter out the questions I answered ("ianswered:0" would show the questions I didn't answer). As it filters out questions, it could be used together with "hasaccepted:1," if I want to find the questions that I have answered which have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Until this is implemented, you could use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for this purpose. Of course, the data will be slightly out of date, depending on the freshness of the latest data dump.

Relevant query: [My answers to questions with no accepted answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64374/my-answers-to-questions-with-no-accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should improve your answer whenever you can, regardless if it is the accepted answer or not. The accepted answer was useful for the OP, but your answer can be useful for a lot of other people  (and the community can vote for your answer). There is even a badge for an answer that outscores an accepted answer, so it is clearly welcomed behaviour in the community.

Comment: OP is saying where there is **NO ACCEPTED ANSWER**, not just that his answer isn't the accepted one.

Comment: @JNK my point is that you should improve your answer even if an answer was accepted, regardless if answer is yours or not.

Comment: this is not practical when you have hundreds or thousands of answers.  It would be beneficial I think to target answers to unanswered questions.  You can probably assume there is a sufficiently clear answer if it has been accepted.

Comment: I agree that it is useful to improve all answers, even if there is a difference accepted answer. However, in the case of a question where no answer is accepted (excluding those askers who will just never accept an answer), a good solution has not yet been found. This feature would help the community focus on unresolved issues more easily.