# list only accepted answer from my answer list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, accepted-answer

I have two questions:

1. How can I filter only accepted answers by OPs that are given by me from my all answer list?
2. How can I filter only accepted answers by OPs out of all answers given by any user? (not necessarily important for me to know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in the answer list, but you can do it with the search feature.

Search the site in question using `isaccepted:1` and `user:[user id]`.

To find all of the accepted answers on a site, simply search "isaccepted:1". To find all of your answers which have been accepted, put your user id<sup>*</sup> in there.

For all of your accepted answers on StackOverflow, you would search "isaccepted:1 user:1355763".

[All of your accepted answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1%20user%3A1355763)

[All accepted answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1)

<sub><sup>*</sup>Note that your user id is different on a site-by-site basis, so you will need to change the search if you want to find your accepted answers on a different site.</sub>

**Note:** For a site-independent search, you can use `user:me`, without needing to worry about your user id on a particular site.

---

As was pointed out in the comments, you can search for your answers that *aren't* accepted by changing `isaccepted:1` to `isaccepted:0`.

Related: you can search for *questions* with or without an accepted answer using `hasaccepted` instead of `isaccepted`. However, you can't combine the two. [Related Feature Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108225/167443).

Comment: And for your not-accepted answers: [isacepted:0 user:1355763](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A0+user%3A1355763&submit=search)