# Can I list my questions where I did not accept an answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View my questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)

I would like to improve my accept rate.

Where can I see questions with an answer that I did not accept?

Comment: I'd also like to see this. Ideally a site-wide method too.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett see the dupe. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

- 1st one is having no answers.
- 2nd one have 2 answers but no answer accepted.
- 3rd have 3 answers out of which one is accepted.

Comment: If you have a lot of questions it takes a long time to go through them.

Comment: How can moving eyes will take much time? Solution suggested by Rory is good for you.

Comment: Rory's question is good, for a single site. I was actually commenting on your solution (the answers are paged and with many answers it's not an ideal solution). :)

Comment: OP want to improve accept rate. If questions are less(or more) in amount then it's easy to move eyes and capture unaccepted answers (instead of search because I am more familiar with my questions tab )By the way when we want to see those questions we will see one by one not all at time. But if anyone wants to count unaccepted then solution suggested by Rory is very good.

Comment: I agree your solution works when there are relatively few questions asked, however personally, I think a good solution would be one where you don't have to skip over many questions to find a few without accepted answers.

Comment: It's upto user. Someone feels search better or someone else to find in own profile's question tab.

Comment: Yes exactly, it's up to the user. I was just expressing my opinion in my first comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a search for:

```
 user:me hasaccepted:0
```

This should bring up all questions that you haven't accepted answers for.

Comment: user:me hasaccepted:0

Comment: @SomnathMuluk thanks - included =)

Answer (score 1):

I just have to go to My Profile -> My Questions and check the questions with an answer that are not marked by the green font.