# Is it possible to see all my questions where I haven't accepted an answer yet across the entire SE network?

Tags: support, questions, accepted-answer, global-search

I am interested in finding all the questions I asked over the entire SE network that I don't yet have accepted an answer for.

I have seen that there is another question for individual SE sites that recommends using the search functionality ([View my questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)), but I have 43 different websites that I've asked at least 1 question on (and there are probably others with even more profiles), so that doesn't really scale.

Is there a global search option somewhere? Or another way to see all my unaccepted questions?