# How to create a list of all questions I answered without accept?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, unaccepted-answer

I saw [View my questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers) but my question is not only about *my* questions. Instead: I would like to get a list of all these questions (on a specific site) which

- I answered to
- which do not have an accepted answer.

Beyond that: how to create that list for questions where my answer is the only one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not too hard; [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/705881/questions-answered-by-me-without-an-accepted-answer) is one for part 1, and [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/705882/questions-answered-by-me-without-an-accepted-answer-with-only-one-answer) is part 2.

For reference, here is the second query (the first one is identical, but leaves out the `q.AnswerCount = 1` condition):

```sql
SELECT q.Id AS [Post Link], a.CreationDate
  FROM Posts AS q
  INNER JOIN Posts AS a ON a.ParentId = q.Id
  WHERE a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
    AND q.AnswerCount = 1
    AND q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you sir.