# Why not mark answered questions in "answers" view?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, accepted-answer

Some time ago I asked how I could figure which of my answers were given to questions that are still open (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299217/how-to-create-a-list-of-all-questions-i-answered-without-accept)).

Further thinking about this: I really find that information helpful - and I suggest that it should be easier to acquire.

For example: when I turn to my profile to the "answer" tab, you basically find **two** things there:

- **white box**: the upvote count for that answer
- in case *any* answer was accepted ... you have a green rectangle instead of the empty one

I think it should be possible (and easy!) to come up with a slightly improved UI experience, like:

- **empty rectangle**, just a number: question doesn't have an accepted answer
- **green rectangle** - question has an accepted answer (but it is not the one I gave)
- **green rectangle** with thick black border - "my answer" is the accepted one

The above is just an example - maybe it would be better to fully rework the display (in order to avoid giving a *new* meaning to the known concept of "just a green box").

And yes - the intent is to easily get to these questions that don't have an accepted answer ... but that *could* have one.